# Just wondering how to use JavaScript to make my input text instead of the page content?

Tags: javascript, html

for example I want to make the  value on input4  instead of the original text on h3"This is header 3". Is there anyway to do it with javaScript？

```
    <html>
    <body>       
    <h1 name="practice"> This is header 1 </h1>
    <p name="practice"> This content is contained inside paragraph one. Again, this is the first paragraph. </p>
        <h3 name="practice"> This is header 3 </h3>
        <p id="paragraph"> This content is contained inside paragraph three. Again, this is the third paragraph.</p>
        <h4 name="practice"> This is header 4 </h4>
        <p name="practice">This content is contained inside paragraph four. Again, this is the fourth paragraph.</p>
        </section>

        <form name ="myform" id="form">
        <fieldset>            
        <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="input3" class="input1" id="input3" value=""/>
        <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="input4" class="input1" id="input4" value="This is header 4"/>
        <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="input5" class="input1" id="input5" placeholder="testing text"/>
        </fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick=""/>
    <body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question and your problem...please tell us more...

Comment: You need to clarify your question.... soo confusing!

Answer (score 0):

What is tag section? Anyway you can use

```
document.findElementById('something').innerHtml = document.getElementById('input_id').value
```

Comment: Glad to see a response that doesn't include jQuery :)

Comment: okey, then the easiest way is to supply an id for that element, using which you'll `findElementById`. Or you can build a chain of `findElementByType` and so on, but that sucks. 

This assignment should be done in some function called on some action (for example, `onclick='yourfunction()'` property on some button element)